# How to provide password to Azure shell?

Tags: azure

I am new to Azure, I tried in shell

```
miroslav [ ~ ]$ sudo su -

We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:

#1) Respect the privacy of others.
#2) Think before you type.
#3) With great power comes great responsibility.

For security reasons, the password you type will not be visible.

sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required
```

Which password is required? The ine from my hotmail account which I am using to setup my Azure resources?

Comment: Why do you need `sudo` or `su`, what are you trying to do?

Comment: @mbj Install newest terraform version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Shell does not support sudo.
Quote from [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/limitations#user-permissions):

> Permissions are set as regular users without sudo access. Any installation outside your $Home directory isn't persisted.